# Как в express отдать статический файл по определенному пути?

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    // Что тут должно быть, чтобы отдать 'test.html', например?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Пример:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/путь/до/test.html')
})
```